# bootstrap website not centered correctly on mobile devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, mobile-devices

My Bootstrap Website.(simmean.com) is works perfectly with laptop.

But when I reach it with my Samsung Galaxy Duos 2(Which is categorized as a Small Device- sm) the website will be little bit to the left and not centered well. I tried with many ways but no use. I also tried to figure out a way through searching. But no results.

Here is the screenshots of it.(I can't direct upload them as I didn't have enough reputation. :( so i add here the links of the screenshot images

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a6VT.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjy4s.png

Comment: can u show us the code for that div ?

Comment: A link to your CSS and markup would be useful. You could create a jsfiddle?

Comment: actually i didn't customize bootstrap css. i'll update with some portion of the code.

Comment: You added a `margin-right: 20px` to the `body` and a `margin-right: 0px` to the `.container`. This breaks Bootstrap's grid, never change horizontal margins or paddings on the `body`, `.container`, `.row` or `.col-...` unless you're absolutely know what you're doing. Removing these properties should be a first step.

Comment: here is a portion of the code of simmean.com on jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/mds5376n/3/

Comment: @ckuijjer oh so sorry.. it was just effort to fix that. I haven't revert that change on the hosting. now it's fixed.

Comment: a couple of notes `column` class have no use , for the search use `input-group-addon` so it doesn't break on resizeing ,bootstrap classes cascades up means something like `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6` could be only `col-xs-12 col-md-6` ,u dont put the clearfix with the row ,instead u put after the div

Comment: thanks @ctf0 . I fixed them. removes,column classes. Add row clearfix again.
input-group-addon class added a background box and i removed the -addon class again.
Anyone got a fix for the issue ??

Comment: what issue ? ,and also update the jsfiddle so others can help.

Comment: I figured out the error..
Its because i add an inline width to the search input
style="width:400px"  remove it fix the centering matter. now the site centered well. but the search box issue is still there. I tried to create a long search box with that inline style.